# Do I have to put `SetTitleMatchMode` on top of the script?

Tags: automation, scripting, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

Sample script:

```
#NoEnv
#Warn
#SingleInstance Force

#IfWinActive Foo ahk_exe foo.exe
  !A::Send Foo

SetTitleMatchMode Regex

#IfWinActive Bar$ ahk_exe bar.exe
  !A::Send Bar
```

When running it, the interpreter throws:

[image]

I want to apply `SetTitleMatchMode Regex` only to `bar.exe`, is it achievable without putting it on top of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [SetTitleMatchMode Remarks](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm#Remarks):

> Every newly launched thread (such as a hotkey, custom menu item, or timed subroutine) starts fresh with the default setting for this command. That default may be changed by using this command in the auto-execute section (top part of the script).

And quote from [The Top of the Script (the Auto-execute Section)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto):

> After the script has been loaded, it begins executing at the top line, continuing until a Return, Exit, hotkey/hotstring label, or the physical end of the script is encountered (whichever comes first). This top portion of the script is referred to as the auto-execute section.